# Package alltt does not typeset double quoting marks

Tags: unicode, typewriter, utf8

For a report I would like to typeset HOL4 code in tt font with the alltt environment.

My code includes U+201C Left Double Quotation Mark and U+201D Right Double Quotation Mark.

The alltt environment does not typeset these characters.

I used the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

suggested at https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/unicode-latex/

Does the tt font lack these glyphs for quoting marks? Or the alltt package does not handle well these?

How can I fix this?

UPDATE

Upon popular request, I give you a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
Type name = “:num”
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

The output I get is:

[image: XeLaTeX output]

And my XeLaTeX version information is:

```
$ xelatex --version
MiKTeX-XeTeX 2.9.7345 (0.999992) (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
(C) 1994-2008 by SIL International, (C) 2009-2012 by Jonathan Kew, (C) 2010-2012 by Han The Thanh, (C) 2012-2013 by Khaled Hosny
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.61.1; using libcurl/7.61.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2.6; using expat_2.2.6
compiled with fontconfig version 2.13.1; using 2.13.1
compiled with freetype2 version 2.9.1; using 2.9.1
compiled with graphite2 version 1.3.12; using 1.3.12
compiled with harfbuzz version 2.5.3; using 2.5.3
compiled with icu version 60.1; using 60.1
compiled with jpeg version 9.3
compiled with liblzma version 50020042; using 50020042
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.8.2; using LibreSSL 2.8.2
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.7348; using 4.7348
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 16.7346; using 16.7346
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6882; using 1.6882
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 8.7350; using 8.7350
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
using teckit version 2.4
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.2
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

Comment: don't let us guess what you are doing, show a small but complete example.

Comment: I will do it tomorrow

Comment: You shouldn't load `fontenc` and `inputenc` with `xelatex`. Removing them should work (can't test now).

Answer (score 1):

User @campa gave an answer that made it work:

> You shouldn't load fontenc and inputenc with xelatex. Removing them should work

And indeed, removing them resulted in:

[image: Missing quoting marks solved]

A lesson is not to trust any LaTeX advice out on the Internet like

https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/unicode-latex/

Comment: To be fair, the advice given in the page you link is correct. Quote: _The `fontenc` and `inputenc` commands used in pdfLaTeX should be omitted when working with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX; the Unicode engines ignore (and give a warning about) `inputenc`, while setting `fontenc` can actually cause some characters (like smart quotes) to not be recognized._

Comment: My bad, i just focused on the code snippet on that page.