# Mathematical Unicode characters in verbatim using XeLaTeX:

Tags: xetex, unicode, verbatim, unicode-math

The alltt environment interprets backslashes literally, and my input text is full of them, so I use the verbatim environment for typesetting code.

It goes fine but it does not typeset a universal quantifier.

XeLaTeX is said to process Unicode better but it fails here.

In my question [Package alltt does not typeset double quoting marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641412/package-alltt-does-not-typeset-double-quoting-marks) a comment reminded me that in XeLaTeX I must not use fontenc and inputenc, so I cannot use

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2200}{$\forall$}
```

I tried the unicode-math package but that did not help either.

How can I typeset Unicode character U+2200 universal quantifier in a verbatim environment using XeLaTeX?

Comment: you need a mono font which has the char, e.g. with `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Iosevka}` it works.

Comment: That is certainly a solution. Thanks indeed, in the long run I should use that. 

As I now write a sloppy (pun intended) technical report, I prefer to find a solution that works without font installation as I use different machines, I reverted to pdflatex and DeclareUnicodeCharacter.